# Short story where a recovering alcoholic scientist uses a chronoscope to try and find out if the Resurrection really happened

Tags: story-identification, novella

Featured in a "best of" anthology between around 2006 and 2015, not an old story.

The ending is a spoiler so:

> For some major events which could have gone both ways it happens that the chronoscope shows both possible versions. The first night he sees the resurrection as portrayed in the bible and is jubilant. The second night he goes to view it again and is found by his boss drunk having seen the disciples deciding to make it all up.

Comment: Yes, he's drunk because he's a Christian and he doesn't know which world he's living in, the one where Jesus did resurrect or the one where his body just rotted away

Comment: Was the word “chronoscope” used in the story or did the device go by a different name?

Comment: @fez - I don't recall it being called a chronoscope, personally. I've definitely read this, though. There was some talk about Christ's body being surrounding by sparkling lights, etc.

Comment: I don't think it was explicitly called a chronoscope in the story, that I think is just the generic name for such devices? Pretty sure your answer is correct, thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is ["Crucifixion Variations"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?81880) by Lawrence Person, originally published in Asimovs' May 1998 and reprinted in "The Mammoth Book of Extreme Science Fiction" in 2006.  It's reviewed [here](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/3343772453)

> A brilliant physicist feels that Jesus Christ saved his life, rescuing
> him from his life of drunkenness and brutality. He finds a way to look
> at events in the past, although what is shown is a possible version of
> the past; if one views the same event more than once, it may be quite
> different. He decides to view the crucifixion and resurrection of
> Christ. His supervisor, who narrates the story, is presented with a
> difficult decision.