# Short story involving looking into the past and parallel versions of Jesus

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

On Episode 352 of the "Flop House" podcast, one of the hosts, Elliott Kalan, mentions recalling a short story from *Asimov’s* sometime in the past 30 years involving:

- A technology involving the ability to view past events, but not actual time travel (just viewing)
- This technology, the further back in time one looked, became less accurate because it might show the past of a parallel timeline as well as the past of our current timeline
- A scientist looks backward and sees the resurrection of Jesus, but then looks again and sees Jesus crucified without any resurrection
- There is a great deal uncertainty and angst caused by the revelation that salvation  does occur, but only in some universes (and it’s not clear which one applies to our timeline)

Does anyone know what story this might be?

Comment: "Crucifixion Variations" again?: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/269086/short-story-where-a-recovering-alcoholic-scientist-uses-a-chronoscope-to-try-and/269097#269097

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I believe we've just had a question about this story; possibly someone else heard the same podcast.  You should try searching; if I find it I'll post a link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short story where a recovering alcoholic scientist uses a chronoscope to try and find out if the Resurrection really happened](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/269086/short-story-where-a-recovering-alcoholic-scientist-uses-a-chronoscope-to-try-and)